# JQuery Mobile + Phonegap Login Page

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova, authentication

I am creating an Android app that uses Jquery Mobile and Phonegap. I am working on a log in page with a couple of fields. How do people normally validate user info in a Phonegap + Jquery Mobile app? Do they use sqlite, localstorage? I can not seem to find any examples of login pages that uses sqlite with a phonegap application. I tried using the examples on the phonegap storage page, but I am still kinda lost. Can you any of you be so kind to give me a starting point or direct me to a resource that shows me how to create an authentication login page in a PhoneGap + JQuery Mobile application? Is this even the proper way to do a login page for a mobile web app? Thank you in advance.

Comment: depends how secure you want the app to be... I personally use webservices to validate user information, but should the user choose to have a 'PinCode' instead of having to input user/pass every time they open the app, I store the username and password with `localStorage`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you show me an example of that? What kind of webservices? Sorry if I sound stupid. I am new to mobile web projects.

Comment: Aahm, we used a little-known layer called JOOB (http://www.joobworld.com/)... It was okay, but I wouldn't recommend it as it doesn't have a lot of documentation - and we only got by because we were working with the team that developed it. As for an example of `localStorage`, there's only a few methods it has: `setItem(name, value)`, `getItem(name)`. You can read here: http://php-html.net/tutorials/html5-local-storage-guide/

Comment: So just use localstorage only for the login page? Will the localstorage database be there if the user closes the app? Thanks

Comment: Yes, `localStorage` persists after the session has ended, and it seems to be there even after the cache has been cleared... at least on iOS. I only used `localStorage` for username/pass when the user set the pincode - because I had to use the username/pass to login with the webservices...

Comment: Ok, thank you so much ahren. That cleared up a lot of things for me. I was using that localstorage example on the phonegap site and ran into some issues. Thanks again friend.

Comment: Bare in mind that while local storage remains after clearing the cache in IOS, it may not in future versions.